# how to create a counter that collects values from an array to pass as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, zooming, increment

I assign to a button a function that executes an external library method for zooming.

```
<div *ngIf="isPremium" class="zoom-in" (click)="zoomIn()"><i class="icon-search-plus"></i>>/div>
```

This method only supports three parameters established by the library itself. Width, height and a third number that performs a zoom increment.

```
  zoomIn() {
    const $container = $('.container');
    this.instance = panzoom($container[0], {
      smoothScroll: false,
      zoomSpeed: 0.015

    });
    const width = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
    const height = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().height / 2;   
    this.instance.smoothZoom(width, height, 2);

  }
```

I tried to pass an array of values directly as a third parameter but it returned an error (ERROR Error: zoom requires valid numbers).I understand that the error it returns is because it only allows a single value.
How could I pass an array of values instead of the third parameter to perform a progressive zoom increment each time I press my button?
thank you in advance for your help

```
 const width = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
    const height = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().height / 2;  
const possibleZooms = [1.2, 1.4, 1.8, 2]; 
    this.instance.smoothZoom(width, height, possibleZooms);
```

Comment: you will have to make sure of that with `onclick`. for the start you can just add the 1st value 1.2 then later on button click you will have to increment that value and set again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, define a variable that  holds the current zoom value, and increase it every time:

```
var currentZoom = 0;
zoomIn() {
    const $container = $('.container');
    this.instance = panzoom($container[0], {
      maxZoom: 2,
      minZoom: 0.4,
      smoothScroll: false,
      zoomSpeed: 0.015
      pinchSpeed: 0.015,
      bounds: true,
      boundsPadding: 0.05,
      beforeWheel(e) {
        const shouldIgnore = !e.altKey;
        return shouldIgnore;
      },
      zoomDoubleClickSpeed: 1,
      transformOrigin: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}
    });
    const width = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
    const height = document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().height / 2;   
    this.instance.smoothZoom(width, height, ++currentZoom);
}
```

I used 0 as the first value, but I don't know if it is like that. Now, every time you press the button, the zoom value increases. If there is a max value for the zoom, you can do:

```
...
currentZoom = min(maxZoom, currentZoom + 1);
this.instance.smoothZoom(width, height, currentZoom);
```

This way, when `currentZoom` is equal to `maxZoom`, it won't increase anymore.

Now, if you have several objects that can be zoomed in, you need to organise the current state for *each* one, but I leave that to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, I have tried your solution and I manage to increase the value in each click, but it does it in such a way that it adds the value 1 as integer, I don't know how to make it pick up the values of the declared array. I don't know if I understood you correctly.